# How do you change the default username in message-mode?

Tags: email

I've been using `notmuch`, via `smtpmail.el` and `getmail` to manage my emails on Emacs, and it all works, although I'm annoyed at how I need to change the name beside my `<email@address>` (defined by `user-mail-address`) on the `From:` header.

I've changed `user-full-name` in my `settings.el`, following the examples here:

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SendingMail

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Outgoing-mail.html

But whenever I go write a new messsage or reply to one, `From:` still shows my debian username.

Comment: Did you try setting `user-mail-address`?

Comment: I've already set it to the right address in my `settings.el`, i've edited my question to reflect that. But what I'm looking for is how to change the name beside that on the `From:` mail heading.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: Check the value of `user-full-name` just before you try to compose the mail: `C-h v user-full-name RET`. If that is not correct, restart emacs and check again. If it is correct, I would instrument the function `message-make-from` with [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html#Edebug) and try to compose an email. When you hit the breakpoint, check a backtrace with `d` and see who called what and how: in particular, if  `message-make-from` is called without an argument, it should use `user-full-name`; if it is called *with* an argument, check the callers.

Comment: Evaluate also `(message-make-from)` with `C-x C-e` after the closing paren. It should return the "right" thing: assuming `user-full-name` is "John Smith" and `user-email-address` is "jsmith@jsmith.net", it should return `John Smith <jsmith@jsmith.net>`. OTOH, if you call `message-make-from` with an argument like this: `(message-make-from "foo")` it is going to return `foo <jsmith@jsmith.net>`.